How to make planes glow?
Basic description of the problem: I have this issue where I want to make these faces have glowing eyes, but I can't seem to find how to do it.
Image 1. I have no idea how to do this part, I heard it requires a plane and making it glow along with the texture to actually make it glow, it also includes the "Project from View" from the UV editor.

Image 2. The second image shows how one of the "planes" look from the side.

Image 3. How a face with the planes looks like, how the eyes look like with the face texture and all.

Image 4. The face texture I want to make its eyes glow with this same plane technique.

Image 5. The plane on its own, making the eye glow on itself.

Image 6. The plane and the eye side-by-side.

Image 7. The face in general, half without the glowing eye and the other half with the glowing eye.

I just wish to do this part, the plane in general myself, but I have no idea what settings I need to put in the plane or what things I need to add/remove.
If i didn't explain it correctly, I'm sorry I don't know English much, I used google translate for this to help me

please do not use capital letters for "normal" writing because it might be considered as shouting and rude. Thx.

Usually you achieve the glow with an emission shader and a bloom/glare.
